# User text input on android without using XML layout

Tags: java, android, input

Ok, i give up
Is there a way to call for user text input(with appearing on-screen keyboard) without using XML layout and all this stuff like findViewById(R.id.editText1)?
Maybe some kind of onEditListener? or something like this...

Comment: Why don't you want to use XML?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use XML layouts. This is the best thing to use for layouts as it can handle the different devices like screens more easily than trying to do it via code, you have a lot more control and readability from the XML layout than trying it any other way

Comment: Im creating some kind of own engine, and already made all stuff like Buttons, ListBoxes and other stuff just with java without layouts, and i want to end up with this style, dont want to combine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this.
First of all im using a SurfaceView(cos itsgonna be a game project), and i made it FocusableInTouchMode(true);
Then i setOnKeyListenerto my View in place where i need it:

```
mContext.getGameView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                if(event.getUnicodeChar() == 0){
                    setName.setTitle(removeLastChar(setName.getTitle()));
                } else
                setName.setTitle(setName.getTitle() + (char) event.getUnicodeChar());}
                return false;
            }
        });
```

setName.setTitle is just a box(rectangle) with a text in it;
Then i created an InputMethodManager:

```
private InputMethodManager imm;
imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

adn whn i need soft keyboard i call it with:

```
imm.showSoftInput(mContext.getGameView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

when want to remove it use:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow((mContext.getGameView().getWindowToken()), 0);
```

But after i made all this stuff i found one unpleasant issue:
it doesnt catch events from cyrillic language...any idea how to get it? Thanks.